# Jenkins: How to terminate Expect script (properly)

Tags: jenkins, tcl, expect

Wrote an expect script to kickoff a build and it works perfectly.  At least, until I started calling it from Jenkins.

I originally wrote the script to use the `interaction` command, to give control back to the user when the script inside the expect script is finished.  Jenkins finishes the script too early, however.  (`interaction` command does not work with Jenkins).

Then I changed the script to use `expect eof` then `wait`, however, now Jenkins never terminates the script.  It just runs forever.

My script looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#This script never finishes
send "KICKOFF_OFF_BUILD.ksh LOCATION\r"
expect eof
wait
```

Is there anyway to change this so Jenkins recognizes the job is finished when the korn shell script inside the expect script above finishes?

Comment: What process (that you need to spawn) are you sending that text to?

Comment: @glennjackman I spawn an rlogin session logging into a server, then I run that script.

Comment: Is the script you show run as a separate process, or is it `source`-ed into the script where you `spawn`? If it's a separate process, you have no connection to the spawned process.

Comment: @glennjackman I believe I run it as a separate process. Are you implying to spawn the process?

Comment: Not a jenkins expert, but where you "spawn an rlogin session", is that done with expect? Does this kickoff script need to be expect?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, it is done with expect.  The same script, too.  Kickoff script does not need to be expect, I guess...but it would be nice to just keep it in the same script.

Comment: Instead of *executing* that kickoff script, `source` it .